# adding alphabets into rows with different value

Tags: excel

Is there way in excel for me to add ABCs into excel rows and have it reset when the value if the row is different? sorry my explanation isn't great, here's a picture to help show what i mean

[image]

As you can see, since there is only 1 record of AC237, it starts with a, so it becomes AC237a. There are 3 records for AC238 the result is AC238a, AC238b and AC238c. Whenever the data value of the row changes, the alphabetical sequence resets. Is this achievable?

Hope to hear from you guys soon and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CHAR` and `CODE` to do this.

```
=IF(A2<>A1,A2&"a",A2&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(B1,1))+1))
```

[image]

If you ever need to restart the alphabet when there are more than 26 instances of the same data in a row, you could use:

```
=IF(OR(A2<>A1,RIGHT(B1,1)="z"),A2&"a",A2&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(B1,1))+1))
```